# Is it possible and/or beneficial to package a Windows Prefetch File with an application?

Tags: windows, performance, deployment, startup, prefetch

I just learned by accident that since Windows XP there is a special system directory `C:/Windows/Prefetch` which contains "prefetch files" used to speed up system boot and application start-up performance. I discovered them by searching my disk with the name of a program of mine and saw a `.pf` file in that directory.

Naturally, I began to wonder if it is possible for me, as the creator of an application, to pre-create these prefetch files myself. The intention is that the users of my application could benefit from better startup performance since the very first launch of my application, rather than the second one, as I understood that the prefetch file is generated only when needed.

Is it possible to create these special files ahead of time, package them with an app, and then install them, or do they have to be created on the end user's machine?

Comment: As this isn't directly related to the question itself, but could be interesting to some nonetheless, here I will mention that to search all the files on my drive very quickly I used an open-source tool called [Wox](https://github.com/Wox-launcher/Wox) that uses a tool called [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com) internally.